# OpenCV Stereo confidence

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Is there a way to get out the confidence from OpenCV's Stereo matching algorithms in Python?

I wish to eliminate points from the generated point cloud based on these confidence values.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, OpenCV does not seem to provide correlation scores with the stereo matcher functions. If no correspondance is found, pixel appears black on disparity map but you have to trust the algorithms implementation.

You can still compute your own error estimate with respect to your camera parameters, baseline and range (see [this](https://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/2009/07/24/how-to-select-the-proper-disparity-value-for-stereo-vision/) page) or if you really need precision or high confidence in your result, you could try to implement some subpixel accuracy correlation such as [this](http://xanthippi.ceid.upatras.gr/people/evangelidis/encc/) one. Hope this helps.